# I need to search the specific row in the web dynamic table with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to search specific row in the web dynamic table with selenium java in chrome driver. I have tried using xpath but I'm able to search only those rows which is displaying on current window, it seems it's not scrolling to check the below rules.

For ex. I have web dynamic table with almost 5k rows. if i opened the table in chrome it will display 22 rows and other will shown after i scroll down the page, So I'm able to search rows only within 22 rows..
is there any way to check all the rows and give me the exact row ??

I have tried like this...

```
//tbody/tr/td/div/span[text()='12345'] -->Created custom xpath for getting estId
String path = "//tbody/tr/td/div/span[text()='"+estId.get(id)+"']";
testElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path));
parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
if (estId.get(id).equals(testElement.getText())) {
flag = true;
break;
}
```

Comment: can you share the url or html?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution you are looking for. But thats the idea.

```
List<WebElement> listRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr"));
for(WebElement e: listRows){
if(e. findElement(By.xpath(".//td/div/span")).getAttribute("innerText").equals("12345")){
flag = true;
break;
}
}
```